# Install imap on PHP 5.4 CentOS

Tags: centos, php

My system is:

- Centos 6.6,
- Nginx 1.8.0 with php-fpm,
- PHP version 5.4.43,

I tried installing IMAP with `yum install php5-imap` but package cannot be found:

```
[root@nv-datacenter ~]# yum install php5-imap^C
[root@nv-datacenter ~]# yum install php5-imap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.usf.edu
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirrors.centarra.com
No package php5-imap available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

When using `yum install php-imap` command, I get a PHP version mismatch error:

```
[root@nv-datacenter ~]# yum install php-imap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.liquidweb.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirrors.centarra.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6 for package: php-imap-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
...
Error: Package: php-imap-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
           Installed: php-common-5.4.43-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.43-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one;

```
yum install php54-php-imap
```

Searching from my x64 box I get the following:

```
Available Packages
Name        : php54-php-imap
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.4.44
Release     : 1.el6.remi
Size        : 58 k
Repo        : remi
Summary     : A module for PHP applications that use IMAP
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP
Description : The php54-php-imap module will add IMAP (Internet Message Access Protocol)
            : support to PHP. IMAP is a protocol for retrieving and uploading e-mail
            : messages on mail servers. PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language.
```

Remi use the following names for there PHP versions;

```
php54-php-foo - php 5.4
php55-php-foo - php 5.5
php56-php-foo - php 5.6
```

Where `foo` is the package name you want.

Having seen your comment [the direct download can be found here](http://remi.check-update.co.uk/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/repoview/php54-php-imap.html) One other thing to check - `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` (Or whatever your version is called) and check to see if you have the following lines and what's enabled.

```
[remi-php56]
name=Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/php56/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/php56/mirror
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

Comment: Still getting No package php54-php-imap available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: @DadaB see my updated answer has a link to a manual download & config section for the .repo file